# Diagonalization of an operator with two Hilbert's subspaces

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, bells-inequality

I was thinking how to diagonalize an operator which is composed by two Hilbert's subspaces. For example, the Bell's operator, which is defined as
\begin{equation}
\vec{B} = \vec{\sigma_1}\cdot \vec{a}(\vec{\sigma_2}\cdot \vec{b}+\vec{\sigma_2}\cdot \vec{b}') + \vec{\sigma_1}\cdot \vec{a}'(\vec{\sigma_2}\cdot \vec{b}-\vec{\sigma_2}\cdot \vec{b}')
\end{equation}
Am I supposed to diagonalize separately each subspace?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot diagonalize the operator separately in general.

The best thing to do is to write the full operator in the tensor product space $\mathcal{H}_1\otimes\mathcal{H}_2$ (in the example you gave that would be a $4\times4$ matrix) and to diagonalize the matrix there.

Comment: Thank you Physer. So I have to multiply two matrices which belong into different subspaces?